# "use of unresolved identifier string" Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble debugging Swift Strings. I want to type in anything listed on the button. I do not want to say in advance about the Code. I get the error when I try to incorporate the following code:

**Full Code here:**  http://climbi.com/b/4444/0

> use of unresolved identifier string

```
@IBAction func Smile() {
    (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText("\(string!)"      
}
```

Comment: What is "string"? It is unresolved for me too!

Comment: The variable named `string` that you're trying to use *is not defined anywhere* in the code you've linked to.

Comment: Please don't post complete listings, post the code that is causing the issue, and any related code

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `string` variable to silence the error.

Assuming `string` has been declared as an optional variable, you can do the following:

```
@IBAction func Smile() {
    (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText(string!)
}
```

Or, if you want to use string interpolation, try

```
@IBAction func Smile() {
    (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText("\(string!)")
}
```

Comment: Still get an error "use of unresolved identifier string"

Comment: @MarinaIOS Please update your question with the code you used to define `string`.

Comment: How about just a snippet?

Comment: This is my problem :)
When I put these codes I get the error

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to do:
Did you create your keyboard using buttons? If so you would have to do something like this:

```
func keyPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(title!)
}
```

Where title property is assigned to the button before hand when you create the keyboard:

Something like this:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
button.setTitle("Smile", forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "keyPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: When I try your way I do not get anything ... weird it does not give me anything I press the keyboard's frost

Comment: did you added a title to the button (button.setTitle("Smile", forState: .Normal)) ? Did you change your target to addTarget?

Comment: I change not just place as you wrote